# Safari X-Frame-Options DENY error on app.facebook.com authentication process

Tags: html, facebook, safari

Safari browser only throws a X-Frame-Options DENY error for my website when iframed on Facebook during the Authentication Process

I have taken my HTML5 PWA website an placed it within a facebook app, setting it up as a "App on Facebook".

My website is being iframed within Facebook:  https://apps.facebook.com/bingotreasure and is pending approval, so it cannot be accessed publicly yet within Facebook apps.

The first page loaded has a "Login with Facebook" button

This Facebook authentication process in my website works without any problems on Chrome, Firefox for MS Windows as well as Chrome for Mac OS.
However, on the same Mac Book that works with Chrome and only on Safari the following error is thrown.

Refused to display https://facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=email&clientid=............'
in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

The fact that only Safari throws this error tells me it must be yet another problem with Safari!

Has anyone found a solution to this error with Safari?

Comment: If it occurs in Safari only, it might have to do with its aggressive blocking of 3rd-party cookies. // Are you redirecting to the login dialog (server-side flow), or are you using FB.login from the JS SDK?

Comment: I am using the server-side flow (redirecting to the fb login dialog) within apps.facebook.com iframe.